# How do I suppress the "number" field in a bibliographic entry of type "@article"?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, chicago-style

I am using latex  together with the `chicago` style. I would like to suppress the `number` field (not page number but number of journal) in the bibliography. How do I do it?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{natbib} 

\begin{document} 
\bibliographystyle{chicago} 
\bibliography{Bib_version_1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a copy of `chicago.bst` (on a TeX Live system it will be found in `/usr/local/texlive/<year>/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/chicago/chicago.bst` where `<year>` is the year of your distribution) and rename it something sensible like `chicago-nonum.bst`. Put this into your local `texmf` folder. On a TeX Live system it should go in `<path-to-local-texmf>/bibtex/bst`. See [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483/2693) for MikTeX information. You should *not* save the new file in the same place as the original file.  You can also put it in the same folder as your `.tex` document, although then it will only be available for  documents in that folder.

In the copied file, find the function `FUNCTION {format.jour.vol}`

Within that function find the following snippet of code:

```
{ volume empty$
  {"no volume for " cite$ * warning$
   "~(" * number * ")" * }
  { "~" *
    volume emphasize.space
    "(" * number * ")" * * }
  if$
}
```

And change it to:

```
{ volume empty$
  {"no volume for " cite$ * warning$
   "~(" * number * ")" * }
  { "~" *
    volume emphasize.space
   * }
  if$
}
```

This will suppress printing the issue number from journal entries, when you use `\bibliographystyle{chicago-nonum}` in your document.